# How to promote nodes to front page using MySQL command line

Tags: 7, nodes, database

What is the command to promote unpromoted nodes to front page using MySQL command line? I want to promote 200 nodes at once. The node type is "story."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UPDATE node SET promote=1 WHERE type="story" AND promote=0 LIMIT 200;`

Comment: Thanks.. but can you tell me how to promote only 200 nodes?

Comment: add `LIMIT 200` and probably also a `SORT BY something`. Or more conditions.